# QnAMaker not returning any answers when two questions with multiprompt answers are asked in a row and rankerType is "questionOnly"

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm creating a simple chatbot where my code is based of the C# sample "QnABotAllFeatures" project form the [Bot Framework samples repository](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples). I have a simple QnA Knowledgebase and use Bot Framework Emulator v4 for testing.

When I set RankerType to only rank by questions, see below, I get no answers from the QnAMaker on my second question if I ask a question with multiturn prompt after another question with multiturn prompt.

```
new QnAMakerOptions
{
    ScoreThreshold = DefaultThreshold,
    Top = DefaultTopN,
    QnAId = 0,
    RankerType = "QuestionOnly",
    IsTest = false
};
```

My knowledgebase looks like this

- Q: Large animals. Answere: Where?

  - Followup Q1: On land? Answer: Elephant
  - Followup Q2: In the ocean? Answer: Wale
- Q: Large plants. Answere: Where?

  - Followup Q1: On land? Answer: Tree
  - Followup Q2: In the ocean? Answer: Kelp
- Q: How are you? Answere: Good

If I ask two questions with multiprompt respons in a row, like "Large animals" then "Large Plats", I get "No QnAMaker answers found." on the last question.

Combinations without two multiturn questions in a row works fine, like: "Large Plants" then "How are you". Or "How are you" then "Large Animals".

If I don't set RankerType, or set it to "default", it all works perfectly.

What am I owerlooking?
I've also tried lowering the ScoreThreshold to 0.01f.

It's repeatable by runnig the C# sample "QnABotAllFeatures" project form https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples and changing RankerType to "QuestionOnly" in the  QnAMakerBaseDialog.GetQnAMakerOptionsAsync method

Comment: Have you tried repeating your repro steps using Postman? I wonder if this is an issue with the QnA Maker API itself versus if it's an issue in the SDK layer. It could be that however QnA's ranking works under the hood, when it looks only at the questions (RankerType=QuestionOnly) that your questions are somehow not distinct enough for the algorithm in the QnA API to discern correctly what the answer should be

Comment: Additionally, if you want the community to help you out with your KB specifically, you could provide some importable version of your KB, so we could better repro the behavior you're experienceing. See [Migrate knowledge base doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/tutorials/migrate-knowledge-base)